# how to update the elements of an array with the sum of previous two and next two elements?

Tags: c++, arrays

how to update the elements of an array with the sum of previous two and next two elements ? given that for the first element the sum would be the sum of next two elements as there is no previous element and same is the case for last element.
for example given an array {1,2,3} the  array will be updated as {5,4,3}
explanation: for 1 there is no previous element so it will be udated as 2+3=5, for 2 there is only 1 previous and only 1 next element so it will be updated as 1+3=4, similarly for 3 it will be 1+2=3.

i tried doing this with if else loops but that seems too confusing and lengthy is there any other way to solve this?

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
if(i==0){
sum=arr[1]+arr[2];
}
if(i==1){
sum=arr[0]+arr[2]+arr[3];
}
if(i==n-1){
sum=arr[n-2]+arr[n-3];

}
if(i==n-2){
sum=arr[n-1]+arr[n-3]+arr[n-4];
}

}
```

the above code does not work for n==3 because element at i==1 will be same as n-2 , also this code is so lengthy. how should i solve this question?

Comment: I think you should first write the algorithm on paper, only then translate it to c++. Write a generic formula for `i`-th element and either evaluate it recursively or think about whether one or two parallel passes through the (reversed) array would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a temporary array to store the initial value of `arr` to prevent calculating the new value of `arr[i]` using new values (post-update) of `arr[i - 1]`, `arr[i - 2]`, etc.

```cpp
std::vector<int> initial_value(arr, arr + n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int updated_value = 0;
    if (i - 2 >= 0) {
        updated_value += initial_value[i - 2];
    }
    if (i - 1 >= 0) {
        updated_value += initial_value[i - 1];
    }
    if (i + 1 < n) {
        updated_value += initial_value[i + 1];
    }
    if (i + 2 < n) {
        updated_value += initial_value[i + 2];
    }
    arr[i] = updated_value;
}
```

Comment: C++ prefer to not use C's calloc / free

Comment: @QuentinUK Yeah, using `std::vector` is preferred.

Comment: @Alwyn it worked thank you!  unfortunate that i couldn't think of such a simple logic

Answer (score 0):

You could use some logic like this if u are looking for minimal code

Psuedo code

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++){
    int sum = 0;
    int startIndex = (i+2) > sizeof(arr) ? sizeof(arr) : (i+2) ;
    while(startIndex > (i - 2) && startIndex > 0)
    {
        if(startIndex == i) continue;
        sum = sum + arrCopy[startIndex];
        startIndex --;
    }
    arr[i] = sum;
}
```